# Google Analytics showing the previous page path as the current page

Tags: google-analytics, url, referrer, path

My data shows that for one of my pages, Previous Page Path and the page are the same. After Googling, I see this can be due to page refreshes or uploads.

I tried to test this out, by uploading/refreshing about 20 times on the page. My Pageviews for that page/previous page path combo only increased by 1 in the custom reporting, not the 20 I would have expected.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you give your activity a full day to appear in GA? And you're not filtering your own traffic out, right?